# Smartface: How to play an audio file?

Tags: smartface.io

```
function StartPage_imgArrow_OnTouch(e)
{
  SMF.Multimedia.playSound("resources://clickOn.mp3",true,false);
}
```

Binding file don't work, is this path wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have sample app about Mp3 player. Make sure you have right file directory.

Here this is my script. This works on Android, I did not tried on iOS.

```
    function Page1_Self_OnKeyPress(e) {
    if (e.keyCode === 4) {
        Application.exit();
    }
}
var mp3path = "";
function Page1_Self_OnShow() {
    //Comment following block for removing navigationbar/actionbar sample
    //Copy this code block to every page onShow
    header.init(this);
    header.setTitle("Page1");
    header.setRightItem("RItem");
    header.setLeftItem();
    /**/
    mp3path = SMF.IO.getExternalStorages();
    mp3path = mp3path[2] + "/" + "two.mp3";
    alert(mp3path);

}
function Page1_TextButton1_OnPressed(e) {
    SMF.Multimedia.playSound(mp3path,
        true, false,
        function () {
        alert("started to play...");
    },
        function () {
        alert("finished...");
    });

}
function Page1_Slider1_OnChange(e){
   SMF.Multimedia.setSoundLevel(Pages.Page1.Slider1.value);
}
function Page1_TextButton2_OnPressed(e){
    SMF.Multimedia.stopSound();
}
```

mp3path is an array returned local storages on Android devices. For detailed information see this [link](http://www.smartface.io/developer/guides/advanced/file-operations/).

Comment: Thank you!   mp3path[2] is undefined, but my file directory is      myProjectName_data\resources\Sounds\                                                          What is the problem?

Comment: Which platform are you tried ios or android? Because get SMF.IO.getExternalStorages(); does not work on iOS. For iOS, you use SMF.IO.File(SMF.IO.applicationDataDirectory, "myProjectName_data\resources\Sounds\") method.

Answer (score 1):

Audio file should be in resources folder.

yourProjectName_data\resources\Sounds\

Than you can write like the code below;

```
function pgMap_btnSetting_OnPressed(e) {
    SMF.Multimedia.playSound("clickOn.mp3",
    true,false,
    function(){alert("started to play...");},
    function(){alert("finished...");});
}
```